# A strange rattling only when accelerating from 0 in cold weather

Tags: honda, civic, noise

I've been quite baffled by this for a while now.

There is an odd rattling, or more like a chain moving, (sometimes it even sounds almost like a trickle)  sound which only occurs in :

1) Cold weather
2) After pressing the gas and starting to accelerate

Now it might be possible the sound continues once I've gotten up to speed and I'm just not hearing it, but it doesn't seem that way.  It certainly isn't audible when I'm slowing down.

I have a 2005 Honda Civic.  Are there any suggestions on what it could be ?  I just changed the Timing belt but I've gotten this sound for far longer before I did that.

Comment: Does your car really have a belt, or is it a chain (Not sure whether you just got someone else to fit it)?  It appears that Honda switched from belts to chains on that year according to a search I just did, but it could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a rattling noise that *I noticed sometime after I had my timing belt replaced* on my civic. I honestly can't remember if the noise occurred before the timing belt change as well, but I may have been paying more attention to the car having major work done on it. Anyway, in my case it turned out to be the lower bolt on the alternator. It was missing entirely.  Purchased another from Honda for $7 (bolt & nut) and put it on... no more rattling.

Other cases of rattling on my civic was from a loose heat shield (between the catalytic converter and under carriage. I just had the shop rip it out.

Comment: Removing the heat shield between the cat and the under carriage is a fire hazard. Catalytic converters get EXTREMELY hot.